# Converting string of character values to decimal values in C without using printf

Tags: c, type-conversion

If a have a string of character values, lets say

```
char charstring[k] = "word";
```

How would I convert the values of that string into a new string of the same length that holds the decimal values of the character string? There is no need to print out the conversion, I merely need a new string with decimal values.

Comment: Please indicate the conversion example.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
char charstring[] = "word";
```

then the string of the same length that holds the decimal values of the character string is `charstring`.  (Every character is stored internally as a number already.)

Answer (score 1):

You already have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char s[] = "word";
    char i;

    for(i=0; s[i]; i++){
       printf("%d or $%x\n", s[i], s[i]);
    }
}
```